# IOS/PHP: Capture success message in app after writing to server database

Tags: php, ios, json

after my app inserts a record in a MYSql database, I would like to capture the ID of the new record and send it back to the app for synching purposes.

The question is how to efficiently capture this and send it back to the app.

Here is code that posts to server.

```
-(void) postToServer: (NSString *) jsonString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.~.com/services/new.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   // NSData *jsonData = [@"{ \"item\": \"hat\" }" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [rq setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    [rq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [rq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *rsp, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
        NSLog(@"POST sent!");
        NSLog(@"Error%@",err);
    }];
}
```

Here is php that I have set to echo insert id.

```
$newid = mysql_insert_id();
echo $newid;
```

However, how can I have this web service send info back to app?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just echo the JSON response (Error/Data) in your PHP then your AsynchronousRequest will give the response back to you:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *rsp, NSData *data, NSError *err) {
    NSLog(@"POST sent!");
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Error%@",err);
    } else {
        NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Results: %@", jsonResults);
        // NSString *insertID = jsonResults[@"insert_id"];
    }
}];
```

PHP:

```
// Set the response type as JSON
header("Content-Type: application/json");

...
    if ($sqlResult) {
        // Return your insertID here
        $response = array("insert_id" => $sqlResult['insert_id']); // example
        exitWithResponse($response);
    } else {
        exitWithHttpCode(400, "Bad Request"); // example
    }
...

# Exit with response
function exitWithResponse($response) {
    $status = array('code' => '200', 'response' => $response, 'error' => NULL);
    echo json_encode($status);
    http_response_code(200);
    exit();
}

# Exit with error code
function exitWithHttpCode($code, $error) {
    $status = array('code' => $code, 'response' => NULL, 'error' => $error);
    echo json_encode($status);
    http_response_code($code);
    exit();
}
```

More about status codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: jsonResults is logging out nil.  Do I need to jsonencode it on server?

Comment: Awesome.  That did the trick.  I guess the function is just using the response from the completion block?

Comment: Yes but its good to send a response to the app to handle the data or errors.